# Hyperconvergence infrastructure software to play with?

Tags: open-source, information-management, virtualization

It looks like the "hyperconvergence infrastructure" (HCI) software became essential trend now - some examples are below:

- [Nutanix](https://www.nutanix.com/hyperconverged-infrastructure/)
- [SimpliVity](https://www.hpe.com/us/en/integrated-systems/simplivity.html)

I want to find out what is real in this trend and what is just marketing pitch. For that I want to try this kind of software on a set of my virtual machines (starting with two of them) - but I don't want to buy any software for now.

The Nutanix web page contains "Try it now" button, but if you click on this button, they will ask for your contact data and promise that their "solution expert" will contact you shortly. I don't want that, and I don't have time for that.

The SimpliVity (part of Hewlett Packard now) web page doesn't contain any information about trial versions at all.

It looks strange to me - I was able to download trial versions of very complex packages in the past - like Intel Professional Studio. This kind of versions typically have licenses, which expire in 30 days, so it's enough to get basic understanding, what the product is and what limitations and constraints it contains.

So - I'd like to play with any *trial version* or *open-source* package, which claims to be the HCI one - if it exists.

Does it?